# Disassociate a file on a feature branch from parent in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to disassociate a file on a feature branch from its parent branch, in that changes to the file on the parent branch will no longer merge into the feature branch?

ie: `app/index.html [develop]` changes should no longer merge into `app/index.html [feature/redesign]` when merging `develop` into `feature/redesign` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself why you want to do this, it sounds backwards. Anyway, the following should work: perform the merge as usual, don't care about what happens to `app/index.html` (that is, in case of conflict just accept something, don't think about it). Then, before doing the merge commit, revert that file to its previous revision on `redesign` branch. To make an example:

```
(on branch redesign)
hg merge develop
hg revert -r redesign app/index.html
```

Now `hg status` will still show `app/index.html` as modified, but if you look at its contents, they are the same as before the merge. Do the merge commit as usual:

```
hg commit -m 'Merge develop into redesign'
```

Note: you must do this each time you do a merge, there is no "dissociate" capability.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete and re-create it on the branch.